# Почему когда я ввожу string с пробелами в cin, то мне выводит только одно слово

Tags: c++, строки, cin

У меня есть проблема в C++, когда я пишу два слова, например, "hello world" в `cin`, то когда оно выводит "hello world", там только "hello".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "RU");
    std::string text;
    std::cout << "что вывести на экран?";
    std::cin >> text;
    std::cout << text;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Оператор `cin >> text;` считывает только одно слово до пробела или символа новой строки. Таким образом, если вы вводите `"Hello world"`, `cin` считывает только `"Hello"` и прекращает считывание при обнаружении пробела.

Вы можете использовать функцию `getline()` для считывания всей строки целиком:

```
getline(cin, text);
```

Comment: Спасибо это реально помогло